# PHP Error: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity

Tags: domdocument, php

Please check this bellow program.

::Program::

```
      <?php
      $xml='
      &lt;books&gt;
           &lt;book&gt;
                &lt;name&gt;Java complete reference&lt;/name&gt;
                &lt;cost&gt;256&lt;/cost&gt;
           &lt;/book&gt;

           &lt;book&gt;
                &lt;name&gt;Head First PHP and Mysql&lt;/name&gt;
                &lt;cost&gt;389&lt;/cost&gt;
           &lt;/book&gt;
      &lt;/books&gt;';


      $dom=new DOMDocument();
      $dom->loadXML($xml);
      foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('book') as $book)
      {
              foreach($book->getElementsByTagName('name') as $name)
              {
                   $names[]=$name->nodeValue;
              }

              foreach($book->getElementsByTagName('cost') as $cost)
              {
                   $costs[]=$cost->nodeValue;
              }
      }
      print_r($names);
      ?>
```

It is shows error:

> DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity

Is this correct way to do this?

If it is correct,  Is there any way to get the proper result without changing this `&lt;` to `<` and `&gt;` to `>`?

Comment: This begs the question why you have `&lt;books&gt;` instead of `<books>` in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be using character entities for `<` and `>` on things that are actually XML tags in the string that represents your XML.  It should be this:

```
$xml='
  <books>
       <book>
...
```

Do that and the warning goes away.

You only need to use character entities for `<` and `>` when they are part of the actual data rather than delimiting an XML tag.

Answer (score 3):

DOMDocument expects the string to be VALID xml.

Your string isn't a valid XML string. You should just use `<` in stead of `&lt;`

Why would you have the htmlentities in that string?

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you supposed to start with something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

to create valid XML? That might be the missing start tag your error is talking about.

Comment: That part (XML Declaration) is optional.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all. Just now i have tried with the method "html_entity_decode()". It is worked for me for this example.

::Code::

```
      <?php
      $xml='
      &lt;books&gt;
           &lt;book&gt;
                &lt;name&gt;Java complete reference&lt;/name&gt;
                &lt;cost&gt;256&lt;/cost&gt;
           &lt;/book&gt;

           &lt;book&gt;
                &lt;name&gt;Head First PHP and Mysql&lt;/name&gt;
                &lt;cost&gt;389&lt;/cost&gt;
           &lt;/book&gt;
      &lt;/books&gt;';


      $xml=html_entity_decode($xml);




      $dom=new DOMDocument();
      $dom->loadXML($xml);
      foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('book') as $book)
      {
              foreach($book->getElementsByTagName('name') as $name)
              {
                   $names[]=$name->nodeValue;
              }

              foreach($book->getElementsByTagName('cost') as $cost)
              {
                   $costs[]=$cost->nodeValue;
              }
      }
      print_r($names);
      ?>
```