# How to make loadXML load my XML file?

Tags: php, xml

For some reason this action gives me a 'invalid returned format'.

```
$dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$ret = @$dom->loadXML($data);
if (! $ret) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'invalid returned format';
    return false;
}
```

I use $data = curl_exec($socket) to retrieve the link to the XML file and i'm able to echo the content type of the file by using this action, so the file exists:

```
if (strpos($content_type, 'text/xml') === FALSE) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'invalid returned format';
    return false;
}
```

How can i make it not ERROR?

Thanks!!!

**Extra code:**

```
curl_setopt($socket, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($socket, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($socket, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($socket, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, (15+5));
curl_setopt($socket, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
$data = curl_exec($socket);
$code = curl_getinfo($socket, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$content_type = curl_getinfo($socket, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
curl_close($socket);

if ($code != 200) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Unable to talk to sm';
    return false;
}

if (strpos($content_type, 'text/xml') === FALSE) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'invalid returned format';
    return false;
} 

$dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$ret = @$dom->loadXML($data);
if (! $ret) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'invalid returned format';
    return false;
}

if ($dom->documentElement->nodeName != 'user') {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'authentication issue';
    return false;
}
```

**XML CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user login="myfile">
    <application id="10" name="test" description="test"> … </application>
    </user>
```

**XML RENDER FILE**

```
$applications = $user->applications();


header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
$dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

$user_node = $dom->createElement('user');
$user_node->setAttribute('login', $user->getAttribute('login'));

   foreach ($applications as $application) {
    $application_node = $dom->createElement('application');
    $application_node->setAttribute('id', $application->getAttribute('id'));
    $application_node->setAttribute('name', $application->getAttribute('name'));
    $application_node->setAttribute('description',     $application->getAttribute('description'));
    foreach ($application->getMimeTypes() as $mimetype) {
        $mimetype_node = $dom->createElement('mime');
        $mimetype_node->setAttribute('type', $mimetype);
        $application_node->appendChild($mimetype_node);
    }
    $user_node->appendChild($application_node);
}

$dom->appendChild($user_node);

echo $dom->saveXML();
exit(0);
```

Comment: I see that u are checking for content type. Sounds like you might be fetching file with headers included and that would make it an invalid xml. If not, u need to post more of your code, including curl part.

Comment: I pasted some extra code!

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely `application/xml` and not `text/xml` (unless you set your headers manually to that or your server, for some strange reason, has it associated with `text/xml`).

If that is not the case, your issue is an invalid xml format of the file you are trying to access. Check it with some online XML validator or drug it in Chrome or Firefox and it should show you synax errors.

**Some suggestions for the future:**

1. Have you tried printing your `$content_type` variable - cause if you have, you could debug it in few mins yourself?
2. You should probably distinguish 2 identical "invalid returned format" messages so you knew which line of code gives you an error.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It would be cleaner if you gave the incoming XML an header `<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>`

Comment: @MackieeE - he actually has xml as a string from curl, so it is not the answer.

Comment: @i-- Good point, oops :) well, I wonder if `simple_xml_load_string` brings the same kind of error? then it's 100% for certain a badly formed XML.

Comment: Judging by comment #1 under could it be same issue as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270141/php-error-domdocumentloadxml-domdocument-loadxml-start-tag-expected ?

Comment: Could it be that for some reason the <?..?> tags are conflicting? Maybe commenting itself out or something?

Comment: One thing I would recommend right away is to add `htmlspecialchars` to your _name_ and _description_ assignments like this `$application_node->setAttribute('name', htmlspecialchars($application->getAttribute('name')))`

Comment: The weird thing is that i just entered the code 'manually' and it worked perfectly $doc = DOMDocument::loadXML('<root><node/></root>'); I pasted the whole file in there without the initial tags and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, there is some kind of illegal syntax issue. Does it break on all users, or just on this particular one? I would look for some weird characters like & and quatation marks in your values, those could be a problem.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<user login="mwilson">-<application description="PDF Viewer" name="Adobe Reader 9" id="10"><mime type="application/pdf"/><mime type="application/vnd.adobe.pdx"/><mime type="application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml"/><mime type="application/vnd.adobe.xfdf"/><mime type="application/vnd.fdf"/></application></user>

Comment: I meant the <?xml version...?> tags. I think the <? ?> is disrupting the format..the minusses are not printed in the actual format, so that's not the problem...mwilson is a fake person btw :)

Comment: found something interesting here...http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=46300

Comment: well, you should be able to fix that by changing the `header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8')` and the part of code that checks for text/xml that.

Comment: that results into this problem $code = curl_getinfo($socket, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); if ($code != 200) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Unable to talk to sm';
    return false;
}

Comment: and before you got the same problem as me?

Comment: supported for backwards compatibility, but we recommend you don't use them. ; Default Value: On
; Development Value: Off
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/short-open-tag
short_open_tag = Off

Comment: yes i did and i still get the same warning message... loadXML(): Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in Entity,